# How to capture a network request and replay it with the same headers in Cypress?

Tags: request, cypress, cypress-intercept

I have a Cypress test in which I navigate to a particular page and that page automatically initiates multiple requests. One of the requests fetches the data and displays it on the UI. In my test, I want to capture that request with all the parameters and headers and replay the same after I click on the log-out button. With this test, I want to ensure that authorized requests return an error code if they are called again with the same authentication headers (cookies) after log-out. I am not even sure if this is possible via Cypress or not. As of now, I do this test manually using tools like Fiddler, Burp Repeater, etc., and want to automate it. Suggestions regarding any other ways to make such tests automatable are also acceptable.

Comment: When you say "replay it" do you mean sending another request? If so, you can do it with cy.request().

Comment: Yeah, I meant sending the same request again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paolo's answer won't work because `capturedRequest` will always be `undefined`. Cypress is asynchronous, so the variable won't have a value by the time `cy.request()` is called, causing it to fail.

The proper way to do this would be:

```js
cy.intercept('*/logout*').as('outRequest'); // Setup intercept and alias to monitor the request

cy.get('#logoutButton').click(); // Initiate the request

cy.wait('@outRequest'); // Wait for the request to come back, this is important

// Resend request and validate status code
cy.get('@outRequest').then((out) => {
  cy.request({...out.request, failOnStatusCode: false}).should(response => {
    expect(response.status).to.eq(401)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

First, capture a request sent by the app with `cy.intercept()`. Then use `cy.request()` to re-send it.

You want to pass the test if the last request fails, so I would try it with the `failOnStatusCode: false`.

The basic pattern would be as follows.

```js
cy.intercept(url, (capturedRequest) => {
  cy.request({
    ...capturedRequest,
    failOnStatusCode: false
  })
  .then(response => {
    expect(response.statusCode).to.eq(505)  // whatever the failure code is 
  })
});

cy.get(logoutSelector).click()
```